# Vector and matrices operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following expression:

$(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\Psi a})^{T}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\Psi a})$

I would like to develop the expression and gather the terms:

$\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{\Psi a} - (\mathbf{\Psi a})^{T}\mathbf{x} + (\mathbf{\Psi a})^{T}\mathbf{\Psi a}$

$ = \mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{x} -2\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{\Psi a} + \mathbf{a^{T}\Psi^{T}\Psi a}$

Why is the last expression is true?

Comment: Is it in case that $\Psi$ is semi-positive definite?

Comment: The transpose of a scalar is the same scalar.  And $x^T \Psi a$ is a scalar and equal to $a^T \Psi^T x$.

Comment: ok that was easy and make sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I could post it as a solution.

Comment: Go for it! I will accept it.

Comment: I've done so and given the question a (+1).  And thank you for the up vote and acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transpose of a scalar is the same scalar.

And note that $x^T \Psi a$ is indeed a scalar.

So, it is equal to its transpose and we have

$$x^T\Psi a= (x^T\Psi a)^T=(\Psi a)^T x=a^T \Psi^T x$$